# Is the restriction of the regular representation of a finite group always a multiple of the subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

For an inclusion of groups $H \hookrightarrow G$, define the restriction $\operatorname{Res}^G_H$ of representations as precomposition with the inclusion map. Also, define the complex regular representation of $G$ as $\mathbb{C}[G]$.

I found that for example $\operatorname{Res}^{\mathbb{Z}_4}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}_4]) \cong \mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}_2] \oplus \mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}_2]$, and in all other examples I checked, $\operatorname{Res}^G_H(\mathbb{C}[G]) \cong \bigoplus^{[G:H]} \mathbb{C}[H]$.

Is there a theorem or lemma stating this property of finite groups? Is it true in other cases as well, say, Lie groups, algebras, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct sum decomposition follows from the fact that $G$ is the disjoint union of the right cosets of $H$, and each of the corresponding subspaces is invariant and behaves like the regular representation of $H$.

This sort of decomposition into invariant subspaces wouldn't exist for most algebras because the cosets in that case are cosets of the addition operation, while the action is given by multiplication. Cosets of an ideal would be permuted by multiplication.

Comment: Nice! Is there a standard reference for that?

Comment: @Turion My answer comes from my own head. In terms of references, the best I can do is recommend a book on representation theory. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful in that respect.